# Call Angular 8 App to .NET Core Web API via Azure B2C

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-authentication

I am working on Angular 8 application that requires to get token from Azure B2C, followed by call .NET CORE Web API. I am following http://about-azure.com/using-azure-ad-b2c-with-angular-8/ Tutorial. I have create Azure Application one for middleware (Web API) and second one for Angular.

I am getting redirect error when I click on 'login' from Angular.

```
 https://localhost/#error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description
```

I believe it did mistake on Web API Application Redirect URL as shown in following screen. I have follow above steps from the above tutorial

### Web API Application On Azure

[image]

### Angular Application On Azure

[image]

### App-Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OAuthService, NullValidationHandler } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { authConfig, DiscoveryDocumentConfig } from './auth.config';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
<h1 *ngIf="!claims">
 Hi!
</h1>

<h1 *ngIf="claims">
 Hi, {{claims.given_name}}!
</h1>

<h2 *ngIf="claims">Your Claims:</h2>

<pre *ngIf="claims">
{{claims | json}}
</pre>
<br />

<div *ngIf="!claims">
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="claims">
<button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
<button (click)="getMessage()">API Call</button>
<div *ngIf="message">
  Response:
  {{message | json}}
</div>
</div>
`,
 styles: []
 })
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private oauthService: OAuthService) {
 this.configure();
  this.oauthService.tryLoginImplicitFlow();
}

message: string;

public getMessage() {
 this.http.get("https://localhost:5001/api/values", { responseType: 'text' })
  .subscribe(r => {
    this.message = r
    console.log("message: ", this.message);
  });
}

public login() {

 this.oauthService.initLoginFlow();
}

 public logout() {
  this.oauthService.logOut();
}

public get claims() {
 let claims = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
 return claims;

}

private configure() {
 this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
 this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new NullValidationHandler();
 this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument(DiscoveryDocumentConfig.url);
 }
}
```

### .WEB API deployment

[image: enter code here]

```
namespace App.Core.API.Controllers
{
  [Authorize]
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
   public class HomeController : ControllerBase
   {
     [HttpGet]
     public IActionResult GetAsync() => Ok("Hello, World");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should confirm the redirect url in Angular app's config is the same as `http://localhost:4200/index.html` , you can use Fiddler or browser's developer tools to trace and find the request url in the authorize request to Azure AD B2C , it must exactly match one of the redirect URIs that you registered in the portal .

Comment: Thanks for the information. So what should be redirect URL for Azure application properties for middleware (.net web API app) ??

Comment: You are doing authentication in angular app , and acquire access token to access your web api , no need to set web api app's redirect url .

Comment: Make sure client(angular) app's redirect url is the same as the one you set on portal .

Comment: You can consider mark this reply as answer which may help others who meet same problem .  Or write a reply shows how you solve the issue if this is not the point .